# Specifying the key:value in the t() from react i18next

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

At the moment I have my UI strings wrapped with `{t('It was a bright cold day in April')}` but that results in my strings being extracted to my en.json file as:

```
'It was a bright cold day in April':'It was a bright cold day in April'
```

Is there a way to specify the string key rather than have the string literal as the key: For example:

```
'bright_cold_day':'It was a bright cold day in April'
```

I am extracting the content using the configuration in my i18next-parser.config file:

````
module.exports = {
  defaultNamespace: 'my-app',
  indentation: 2,
  keySeparator: false,
  lexers: {
    ts: ['JavascriptLexer'],
    tsx: ['JsxLexer'],
    default: ['JavascriptLexer'],
  },
  lineEnding: 'auto',
  locales: ['en'],
  namespaceSeparator: false,
  output: normalize(`${__dirname}/public/assets/i18n/$LOCALE.json`),
  sort: true,
  useKeysAsDefaultValue: false,
};```
````

Comment: Sure there is, but I guess you're asking in the context of some json auto-generation. Would you reveal to us what it is?

Comment: I am extracting the content using the configuration in my i18next-parser.config file: const { normalize } = require('path');
module.exports = {
  defaultNamespace: 'my-app',
  indentation: 2,
  keySeparator: false,
  lexers: {
    ts: ['JavascriptLexer'],
    tsx: ['JsxLexer'],
    default: ['JavascriptLexer'],
  },
  lineEnding: 'auto',
  locales: ['en'],
  namespaceSeparator: false,
  output: normalize(`${__dirname}/public/assets/i18n/$LOCALE.json`),
  sort: true,
  useKeysAsDefaultValue: false,
};

Comment: The code pasted into comments here is unreadable and sorry, but idk this method...

Comment: To add more context, I've tried  {t("fruit", "Orange")} and that gives me the correct JSON format. However, when I change that value to "Apple" and run the extraction script again, the fruit:Orange key value pair doesnt get updated and remains the same.